# crypto-js wrong des-ecb decoding

Tags: javascript, algorithm, cryptography, cryptojs, des

I need to decrypt base64 string using base64 key with ECB mode and Iso10126 padding using DES.

In theory it is simple:

```js
const decryptedKeyDes = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt(
      encryptedData, // QAKH7qnKxZTIta...
      ResponseParser.secretKey, // MfKhm... length=32
      {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Iso10126
      }
    );
```

I get `sigBytes:162`response and after converting it to base64 (because then I need to ungzip) I get 
`byteLength:243` which is wrong, it should be `byteLength:395` (I am just compering it with my correct Java code).

I have no idea what is wrong here.

I also tried to do it using node.js's `crypto` but I also get wrong and different result. I can't find how to set `padding` in `crypto` and I can get only `utf8`, `binary` or `ascii`

```js
function encodeDesECB(textToEncode, keyString) {
      var key = new Buffer(
        "some key with 32 length".substring(0, 8),
        "utf8"
      );
      var cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("des-ecb", key, null);
      cipher.setAutoPadding(false);
      var c = cipher.update(textToEncode, "base64", "utf8");

      c += cipher.final("utf8");
      return c;
    }
```

The java code is:

```java
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import static javax.crypto.Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE

//CIPHER_ALGORITHM_MODE_PADDING = 'DESede/ECB/ISO10126Padding'

Cipher decryptingCipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM_MODE_PADDING)
      decryptingCipher.init(DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec)
      decryptingCipher.doFinal(data)
```

where `secretKeySpec` is object with `algorithm: DESede` and `key`, which is `bit[]` equal to mine.

I have no idea what is wrong in my code.

Does `CryptoJs` works wrong, or maybe I forgot about something in my decoding.

Do you have any clues what can be wrong?

Comment: An obvious bug is that in the Java reference code DESede is used and in the JavaScript/NodeJS code DES. DESede, also known as [TripleDES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES), is based on DES, but isn't identical to DES. The results are different. Other possible sources of error regarding [CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input) are the data types, e.g. the key must be passed as `WordArray` and not as string (if it should be processed as key and not as password).

Comment: @Topaco, that is a good spott, with TripleDES. Thanks. How I can create `WordArray`? I am trying to do so by `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('QAKH7qnKxZTIta...')` and `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('some key with 32 length')`, and the result is empty `
sigBytes:0`.

Comment: CryptoJS provides encoders for the _`WordArray` <-> string_ conversion. For example, for a Base64 encoded string, the Base64 encoder must be used to convert the string into a `WordArray`. [Here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders) you can find examples for the various encoders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Topaco I finally solved it.

The key has to be `WordArray`: `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('some key with 32 length')`

The message has to be base64 string: `QAKH7qnKxZTIta...`;

Then you need to parse the response like this: `tripleDesResult.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)`

Thanks again!